# I can't insert data inTO my sql table using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having this issue for days now, every SQL command (i am using PDO statements) work except INSERT INTO (i am able to SELECT and CREATE tables, but not to add data from my form into it ). I have checked and I have all the privileges that i need + i have tried all the versions of this code i could find online but nothing seems to work. Any idea?
//Sorry for the pic, it's my first post and i did'nt knew.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post"> 
        <input class="input" type= "text" name="nom" placeholder="nom" required> <br>
         <input class="input" type= "password" name="password" placeholder="password" required><br>
         <input class="button" type= "submit" value="Signup"> 
     </form>  <br>
      
</body>
</html>


<?php

//connessione bd
try {
 

  $bd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ems_db;charset=utf8", "root", "root");
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
 
  
  echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}


//recupero



$arr['nom'] = $_POST ['nom'];
$arr['password'] = hash('sha1', $_POST ['password']);

print_r($arr);



//

$sql = 'INSERT INTO users ( nom, password) VALUES( :nom, :password,)';

$statement = $bd->prepare($sql);

$statement->execute([
  ':userid' => $arr['userid'],
    ':nom' => $arr['nom'],
    ':password' => $arr['password'],
    ':rankid' => $arr['rankid'],
]);


$publisher_id = $bd->lastInsertId();

echo 'The publisher id ' . $publisher_id . ' was inserted';
```

Comment: Use [PDOStatement::errorInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php). Also, please post code as text, not as pixels.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried catching exceptions and printing the PDOException message?

Comment: Post your code as text, not images; add the **complete** text of any error messages you see; take the [tour] you were offered when you posted this question; see [ask]

Comment: Thanks for your Answers and sorry everyone! I did not knew

Comment: your array of parameters in the `execute` has more key-value pairs (4) than the actual SQL stament requries (2).  Also not certain about the last 'virgule' in the SQL statement proper.

Answer (score -2):

to answer your problem, to insert a data, the whole line must be inserted, you can't just insert one data but several data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3SO2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbdv3.png)

Comment: Nothing wrong with French and images, but this is an English site, and, as you can read above, you should try to post code as text.

Comment: okay, sorry I'm still new to this site

Comment: That's fine. We all had to learn how this site works. Don't let it put you off.